# Toast message on lock screen in android L

Tags: android

I am not able to display toast message on locked screen in android L. I am trying to display the toast on an activity.

Note: The same code works on KitKat

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Displaying toast!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Please post your code first

Comment: paste your logcat error as well.

Comment: No error occurred. Also in the hierarchy view it can be seen that the toast is getting displayed.